# Forms Authentication Cookies

Tags: c#, forms-authentication

I have WebAPI 2.0 project. I am using Forms Authentication.

My goal is - when administrator changes user password then I want to delete user` cookies.

Is there an option like

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
```

but not for given user, user because the current one is administrator?

Is it even possible to 'iterate' through cookies ?

Thanks in advance!